# 'E-Mail a Link' Ribbon Button generates a wrong URL on Grouped Views

Tags: 2010, list-view, ribbon, library, splist

When a Grouped View is defined in a List View Web Part, the OOB Ribbon Button 'Email a link' on a List/Library Context Tab, generates an incomplete URL (only Web Application URL)

Override the Ribbon Button or change the View are obvious solution, however, any other ideas how to correct this SP malfunction?

Regards

Comment: What is the malformed url like? Is there something like _.000 in the URL?

Comment: Web Application URL only